# How to move out of auto-completed quotes or parentheses in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I find myself wondering how to move the cursor out of a pair of auto-completed double quotes "" or parentheses (). In Eclipse after I finished typing in a pair of brackets, pressing tab brings me out of the brackets. How can I do the same thing in RStudio without using the arrow keys repeatedly?

Comment: Suppose I type `c(` this autocompletes to `c(|)` where `|` is the cursor. Now I type `"` which autocompletes to `c("|")`. Is there a shortcut which brings me outside the double quotes once I finished editing what's inside them? Suppose I have `c("Hello,| Gruffalo!")`, now when I press that desired keyboard shortcut I get out of the double quotes `c("Hello, Gruffalo!"|)`. If I press the same shortcut the second time, I get out of the parentheses `c("Hello, Gruffalo!")|`. The example I am giving is simple but I hope you get the idea - this is to avoid abusing the arrow key.

Comment: And anything `vim` flavoured is off the table, please :)

Comment: I suspect what I am after is a touch of structural editing.

Comment: I see. although `c("Hello,| Gruffalo!")` is simply `f)a` in vim :} or A depending

Comment: maybe [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts) is a start, I don't have the newest version so I can't check if it is possible to remap the tab to do exactly what you want

Comment: @rawr I'm not sure if ctl + p and opt + right/left (ctl + right/left for windows/linux)  were implemented in 2016, but currently you can do much of this.

Comment: @DanHall but `f)a` translates to `f`orward to `)` and insert `a`fter, what does control pee mean :}

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the exact case, you may find ctl + p and opt + right/left (ctl + right/left for windows or linux) helpful. The differences depend on whether there is text inside the quotes or not, and if there is text, where you are in that text.

opt + right moves you to the end of a word pattern or the beginning of the next word pattern. In some cases, a single arrow key is what makes the most sense.  ctl + p takes you to the enclosing parens or brackets

Here are some examples with "|" representing the cursor

**start: `c("|")`**

opt + right: `c("")|`

opt + left: `c|("")`

ctl + p: `c(|"")`

right: `c(""|)`

In this case, the most direct route to the outside of the quotes, but inside the parens is a single right arrow. If you aren't inside the empty "", though...

**start: `c(|"")`**

opt + right: `c("")|`

opt + left: `c|("")`

ctl + p: `c(""|)`

In this case, the most direct route to get outside the quotes to the right, but inside the parens is ctl + p. To get out of the parens, it's opt + arrow (or the end of line combination)

Lets try it with some text:

**start: `c("Hello, |Gruffalo")`**

ctl + p: `c("Hello, Gruffalo"|)`

opt + right: `c("Hello, Gruffalo|")`

Here since you have text inside the quotes, ctl + p gets you outside the quotes, inside the parens, and opt + right gets you to the end of the quote, but still inside. It's different if you have punctuation or whitespace.

**start: `c("Hello,| Gruffalo")`**

ctl + p: `c("Hello, Gruffalo"|)`

opt + right: `c("Hello, |Gruffalo")`

opt + right * 2: `c("Hello, Gruffalo|")`

Now for your specific example from the comments:

**start: `c("Hello,| Gruffalo!")`**

ctl + p: `c("Hello, Gruffalo!"|)`

From there, to get outside the parens, you can use the very complicated key combination of the right arrow alone.

Because the quoted phrase ends in punctuation, you can't get there with opt + right. Follow it through and you'll see it skips from the end of the word to outside the parens (hitting the key combinations three times):

opt + right * 1: `c("Hello, |Gruffalo!")`

opt + right * 2: `c("Hello, Gruffalo|!")`

opt + right * 3: `c("Hello, Gruffalo!")|`

Here are two useful examples if anyone wants to monkey around with this. Try starting inside different nested positions of parens and braces and see how you can use these key combinations to jump around:

```
list(x = c("Hello, Stack Overflow!"), y = c("This is how you jump"))

nulls <- replicate(1000, {
    all <- sample( c(controls, treatments) )
    new_controls <- all[1:N]
    new_treatments <- all[(N+1):(2*N)]
    mean(new_controls) - mean(new_treatments)
})
```

Note that in any of these cases: cmd + right, cmd + left (or end, home for windows/linux) will take you to the end or beginning of a line respectively.

Comment: what's this controls/treatment bit?

Comment: @rawr just a multi line example with nested parentheses and curly brackets, but no character vectors from a file of mine. Copy and paste, put your cursor in different locations, and see how ctl+p and opt + arrow can and can't move you around

Comment: what is 'opt' ?

Comment: @Qbik if you're using windows or linux, ctl should work in the key combinations where opt is used on a mac, e.g., ctl + right instead of opt + right. There's a lot of text in this answer, so I can see how this would be easy to miss :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use control+e to go to the end of a line, and control+a to go to the beginning of a line. At least in Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be typing again the same quotation mark used before, while the cursor is at the end of the quote. Let's assume this `|` is the cursor as in the previous answer:

`shift+#: '|'`
The same combination of keys will bring the cursor out of the quotation marks
`'|' + shift+# -> ''|`

Also
`shift+2: "|"`
And
`"|" + shift+2 -> ""|`

This works *only* when the cursor is at the end of the text written in quote:
`"Hello world|" + shift+2 -> "Hello world"|`
While
`"Hello |world" + shift+2 -> "Hello "world"`.

As for parenthesis, typing the same command will only result in nested parenthesis.
For instance:
`shift+8: (|)`
and
`(|) + shift+8 -> ((|))`

I have just tried this on RStudio 1.4 with QWERTZ keyboard.